# Using the Sublime Video Wordpress plugin, how can I add the sharing buttons to share the permalink?

Tags: video, wordpress, sharing, permalinks, shortcode

I've installed the [Sublime Video Wordpress plugin](http://sublimevideo.net) and have configured settings for the default video. I have also added my local domain to the site wide settings.

In my post I have this shortcode:

```
[sublimevideo width="100%" settings="youtube-id:P5qdfTIrOw8; autoresize:fit"]
```

This displays the video correctly in my responsive layout.

If I was coding this into the theme, I could add the data-sharing-url attribute to my `<video>` as they document [here](http://docs.sublimevideo.net/addons/sharing).

But is there a short code for that? I tried this...

```
[sublimevideo data-sharing-url="http://permalink.com"]
```

I also tried this...

```
[sublimevideo settings="data-sharing-url:http://permalink.com"]
```

Neither of them worked. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

`[sublimevideo settings="sharing-url:http://permalink.com"]`

Comment: Yes, this works, and now I feel silly. Thank you! I should have noticed that "data-" had been stripped from the other settings attributes. I think it had been a long day when I asked this. Is there a way to set the WP permalink to be the default sharing link, rather than setting the "sharing-url" for each post?